# How to create multiple folders with names, and extract multiple zips to each different folder, with python?

Tags: python, directory, zip, extract

I'm having trouble creating many different directories for a number of different zip folders containing different raster data and then extracting all the zips to the new folders in a clean script.

I have accomplished my task by my code is very long and messy. I need to have folders that are labeled like `NE34_E` , `NE35_E` etc, and then within these directories, I need subfolders such as `N34_24` , `N34_25` etc. which the raster data will be extracted to. I have over 100 zip files that need to be extracted and placed in subfolders.

After making some changes to the way I was making directories this is a sample of my script.

My file structure goes like this:

> ```
> N\\N36_E\\N36_24
> N\\N36_E\\N35_25
> ... etc.
> ```

Zipfile names:

> ```
> n36_e024_1arc_v3_bil.zip
> n36_e025_1arc_v3_bil.zip
> n36_e026_1arc_v3_bil.zip
> ... etc.
> ```

Python code to create the directory structure:

```
import os

#Create Sub directories for "NE36_"
pathname1 = "NE36_"
pathname2 = 24
directory = "D:\\Capstone\\Test\\N36_E\\" + str(pathname1) + str(pathname2)
while pathname2 < 46:
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
    pathname2 += 1
    directory = "D:\\Capstone\\Test\\N36_E\\" + str(pathname1) + str(pathname2)

#Create Sub directories for "NE37_"
pathname1 = "NE37_"
pathname2 = 24
directory = "D:\\Capstone\\Test\\N37_E\\" + str(pathname1) + str(pathname2)
while pathname2 < 46:
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
    pathname2 += 1
    directory = "D:\\Capstone\\Test\\N37_E\\" + str(pathname1) + str(pathname2)
```

Comment: You have not used the correct tags, this is 100% not [tag:batch-file] syntax. In order for your question to be viewed by an audience who are knowledgeable on that tag, you are advised to review how you have presented your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import glob, os, re, zipfile

# Setup main paths.
zipfile_rootdir = r'D:\Capstone\Zipfiles'
extract_rootdir = r'D:\Capstone\Test'

# Process the zip files.
re_pattern = re.compile(r'\A([a-zA-Z])(\d+)_([a-zA-Z])0{0,2}(\d+)')

for zip_file in glob.iglob(os.path.join(zipfile_rootdir, '*.zip')):

    # Get the parts from the base zip filename using regular expressions.
    part = re.findall(re_pattern, os.path.basename(zip_file))[0]

    # Make all items in part uppercase using a list comprehension.
    part = [item.upper() for item in part]

    # Create a dict of the parts to make useful parts to be used for folder names.
    # E.g. from ['N', '36', 'E', '24']
    folder = {'outer': '{0}{1}_{2}'.format(*part),
              'inner': '{0}{2}{1}_{3}'.format(*part)}

    # Build the extraction path from each part.
    extract_path = os.path.join(extract_rootdir, folder['outer'], folder['inner'])

    # Perform the extract of all files from the zipfile.
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, 'r') as zip:
        zip.extractall(extract_path)
```

2 main settings to set values, which is:

1. `zipfile_rootdir` is where the zip file are located.
2. `extract_rootdir` is where to extract to.

The `r` before the string is treat as raw string,
so backslash escaping is not needed.

A regular expression is compiled and used to extract
the text from the zip file names used for the
extraction path.

From zip file:

> ```
> n36_e024_1arc_v3_bil.zip
> ```

extracts a part sequence with use of a regular expression:

> ```
> n, 36, e, 24
> ```

Each item is uppercased and used to create a dictionary
named `folders` containing keys and values:

> ```
> 'outer': 'N36_E'
> 'inner': 'NE36_24'
> ```

`extract_path` will store the full path by joining
`extract_rootdir` with `folder['outer']` and `folder['inner']`.

Finally, using a Context Manager by use of `with`, the zip files will be extracted.

---

#### Regular Expression:

```
re_pattern = re.compile(r'\A([a-zA-Z])(\d+)_([a-zA-Z])0{0,2}(\d+)')
```

The compile of the regular expression pattern before
the loop is to avoid multiple compiles of the pattern
in the loop.
The use of `r` before the string is to inform Python
that that the string should be interpreted as raw
i.e. no backslash escaping.
Raw strings are useful for regular expressions as
backslash escaping is used for the patterns.

The regular expression pattern:

> ```
> \A([a-zA-Z])(\d+)_([a-zA-Z])0{0,2}(\d+)
> ```

The string for the regular expression to work on:

> ```
> n36_e024_1arc_v3_bil.zip
> ```

1. `\A` Matches only at the start of the string.
   This is an anchor and does not match any character.
2. `([a-zA-Z])` Matches any alphabet character.
   `[]` is match any characters within.
   Any character between the range of `a` to `z` and
   `A` to `Z` is matched. `n` will be matched.
   The enclosing `()` is store that group captured into
   the returned sequence. So the sequence is now `n,`.
3. `(\d+)` Matches 1 digit or more. The `\d` is any digit
   and `+` tells it to keep matching more.
   Sequence becomes `n, 36,`.
4. `_` is literal and since `()` is not enclosing it, it
   is matched though is not added to the sequence.
5. `([a-zA-Z])` Same as point 2.
   Sequence becomes `n, 36, e,`.
6. `0{0,2}` Match a zero `0`, zero to 2 times `{0,2}`.
   No `()`, so not added to the sequence.
7. `(\d+)` Same as point 3.
   Sequence becomes `n, 36, e, 24`.
8. The rest of the string is ignored as the pattern
   has reached it's end. This is why the `\A` is
   used so the pattern cannot start anywhere and
   proceed to the end of the string that is not wanted.

#### Formatting:

Sequence is `N, 36, E, 24` after being uppercased
by the list comprehension.

1. The pattern `{0}{1}_{2}` is ordered `0, 1, 2`,
   so 0 is `N`, 1 is `36` and 2 is `E` to become
   `N36_E`. The `_` is literal in the pattern.
2. The pattern `{0}{2}{1}_{3}` is ordered
   `0, 2, 1, 3`. 0 is `N`, 2 is `E`, 1 is `36`
   and 3 is `24` to become `NE36_24`.

#### References:

- **Python 2:**

  - [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module for the regular expressions.
  - [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting) method for the formatting of strings.
  - [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) used to uppercase items in the sequence.
  - [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/zipfile.html) module for working with zip archives.
- **Python 3:**

  - [re](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html) module for the regular expressions.
  - [format](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting) method for the formatting of strings.
  - [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) used to uppercase items in the sequence.
  - [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/zipfile.html) module for working with zip archives.

Comment: Hi Michael Thanks for your help! Im wondering if you can help me a little more, ive actually changed things a little but ive got the file sturcture created! Is there any way to create a script that would read the number of n34_e025_1arc_v3_bil.zip and extract it to the given folder?

Comment: The reason my answer is not a complete script is because I do not have all the information to achieve it. Your comment is still unknown as you *changed the structure* and want to *extract to a given folder*. I need to understand what that means i.e. *given* is too broad. If you could base your details on small amount of files, and perhaps use the `tree` command from a prompt (like `tree /a /f` in each dir) to show the structure and paste to update the question. If I can replicate the structure needed, I could possibly make a full script and test, to do what is needed.

Comment: I apologize I am still learning, ill make an edit with the changes ive made and more information!

Comment: Updated the answer based on the latest directory structure. Try it and see if I did it correct with text extraction, order of parts etc.

Comment: Just updated an old comment in the code to avoid confusion. Be aware that the zip extraction will create the directory structure so code to make the directories is not needed.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thank you! Im going through the code now to see if it works for me! Just a question though, what exactly are you doing with the code in the brackets for re.compile?

Comment: Hi Michael, that script worked flawlessly. I was just wondering how i might tweak it to recognize other zip file names, unrelated to this ones i have provided you?

Comment: Updated code with minor changes. With documenting of regular expression pattern, noticed `\w` can match digits so changed to `[a-zA-Z]` to restrict to alphabet. The `glob` pattern changed from `n*.zip` to `*.zip` to get all zip file names. The further documenting added may help answer any questions so far.

Comment: Hi Michael, everything has been going great! Been changing the script in order to get what I need. Im sorry to bother you again, but i have one more question. When using the re_pattern, if i have a zip file with no numbers, named like this (hotosm_tur_points_of_interest_gpkg.zip) how might i change the re_pattern script to match and rename this pattern?

Comment: Hi Michael i actually got it to work the way i wanted for the above comment, but it caused another question. Will this script work to unzip .tgz?

Comment: ive been trying to change everything in your script to tar_file but im getting index errors, probably due to the repattern. My file name is DZB1213-500119L002001_2.tgz

Comment: With `hotosm_tur_points_of_interest_gpkg.zip` and `DZB1213-500119L002001_2.tgz`, I do not see a pattern to work with to get the parts for the folder names to extract to, so I do not understand. Can .tgz be extracted, importing [tarfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html) seems like the solution.