# How to extract a number of tar.gz files to a directory?

Tags: python, extract, tar, gzip

Im trying to extract a number of tar.gz files with no success.

Ive tried to modify a code I was using to extract zip files. Below is my file structure, files and some code.

File Structure:

```
D:\\Test\\Tar
```

File Names:

```
DZB1212-500258L004001_4.tgz
DZB1213-500119L002001_2.tgz
DZB1213-500119L006001_6.tgz
```

Code I've tried:

```
import glob
import os
import re
import tarfile
import gzip
import shutil
os.chdir('E:\\SPRING2019\\SILKROAD\\Folder_Extraction_Auto\\SRTM_DEMs\\TESTEXTRACTER3\\USGS_Declassified\\Declass2_2002')

#set up pathing
tarfile_rootdir = ('E:\\SPRING2019\\SILKROAD\\Folder_Extraction_Auto\\SRTM_DEMs\\TESTEXTRACTER3\\USGS_Declassified\\Declass2_2002')
extract_rootdir = ('E:\\SPRING2019\\SILKROAD\\Folder_Extraction_Auto\\TEST')

#process the zip files [a-zA-Z] to [\w] and removed the _ seperating the two WORKED!!!!!!!!!!!!
re_pattern = re.compile(r'\A([\w+]*)')
#CHANGED ABOVE CREATED HTO_O with no subfolers but all extracted
for tar_file in glob.iglob(os.path.join(tarfile_rootdir, '*.tar.gz')):
    part = re.findall(re_pattern, os.path.basename(tar_file))[0]
    part = [item.upper() for item in part]
    folder = {'outer': '{0}{1}{2}{3}'.format(*part), 'inner': '{0}{1}{2}{3}'.format(*part)}
    extract_path = os.path.join(extract_rootdir, folder['outer'])
    with tarfile.open(tar_file, 'r:gz') as tarfile:
        tar_file.extractall(extract_path)
```

It will run, but nothing happens.

Comment: This fix got it to work! Except im coming up with a Key Error. Saying my filename cant be found but it is set correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import glob, os, re, tarfile

# Setup main paths.
tarfile_rootdir = r'D:\SPRING2019\Tarfiles'
extract_rootdir = r'D:\SPRING2019\Test'

# Process the files.
re_pattern = re.compile(r'\A(\w+)-\d+[a-zA-Z]0{0,5}(\d+)')

for tar_file in glob.iglob(os.path.join(tarfile_rootdir, '*.tgz')):

    # Get the parts from the base tgz filename using regular expressions.
    part = re.findall(re_pattern, os.path.basename(tar_file))[0]

    # Build the extraction path from each part.
    extract_path = os.path.join(extract_rootdir, *part)

    # Perform the extract of all files from the zipfile.
    with tarfile.open(tar_file, 'r:gz') as r:
        r.extractall(extract_path)
```

This code is based similar to the
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56505391/9012170)
to your last question. Due to uncertain information on
directory structure, I will provide a structure as an
example.

TGZ files in `D:\SPRING2019\Tarfiles`:

> ```
> DZB1216-500058L002001.tgz
> DZB1216-500058L003001.tgz
> ```

Extract directory structure in `D:\SPRING2019\Test`:

> ```
> DZB1216
>     2001
>     3001
> ```

The `.tgz` file paths are retrieved with [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html).

From example filename: `DZB1216-500058L002001.tgz`,
the regular expression will capture 2 groups:

- `\A` is an anchor at the start of the string.
  *This is not a group*.
- `(\w+)` to match `DZB1216`.
  *This is the 1st group*.
- `-\d+[a-zA-Z]0{0,5}` matches up to the next group.
  *This is not a group*.
- `(\d+)` to match `2001`.
  *This is the 2nd group*.

The extraction path is joined using the values of
`extract_rootdir`, `DZB1216`, and `2001`.
This results in `D:\SPRING2019\Test\DZB1216\2001`
as the extraction path.

The use of [`tarfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html)
will extract all from the `.tgz` file.

Comment: You must be a teacher... or a wizard. Either way you are passing a lot of knowledge to some students who appreciate your help! Thanks a lot that worked perfectly! :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your filenames are *.tgz, but your glob is *.tar.gz!

Comment: The file extension shouldn't matter, you can theoretically call a file whatever you like with tar. If you're on Linux, you could try the 'file' command, which will tell you if it's really a gzipped tar file or not.

Comment: I keep getting and index error on this line:  folder = {'outer': '{0}{1}{2}{3}'.format(*part), 'inner': '{0}{1}{2}{3}'.format(*part)}

Comment: From what I can see, your regex is matching the first character of the filename, so for all of the above files, the value of `part` is 'D'. When you then pass that to `format`, it is a list of length 1, but your format string wants 4 values. Should your regex be `r'\A([\w]*)'`?

Comment: I still can't get any results!

Comment: [commenting here as I don't have the reputation to comment on your question yet]
@michael_heath is correct, though I would advise against re-using the name `tarfile`, as that conflicts with the imported module name.

In fact, in the last line, you're using `tar_file` (note the underscore). I would suggest a change to:
`with tarfile.open(tar_file, 'r:gz') as t:
        t.extractall(extract_path)`

Usually I'd suggest full names for variables, but we're running out of ways to say "tar file". Perhaps `tar_file` in the for loop should be called `tar_file_path` for extra clarity?

Comment: @SamuelRice Good advice. My mistake, as I did not notice the variable name `tarfile` was also the module name. I deleted the comment containing the mistake to avoid it's use.